# Apache: How can i see my localhost on 192.168.1.101 from 192.168.1.102?

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu. My IP address is 192.168.1.101

While http://localhost and http://192.168.1.101 work fine in my PC, I cannot access it from within my laptop using http://192.168.1.102

It's strange. I can ping 192.168.1.101 but I got "**The connection has timed out**." in browser.

I'm using default apache config. so this is what my `sites-available/default` looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/www/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/www/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

    </Directory>
```

`/etc/apache2/posrts.conf`
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

my laptop runs Ubuntu as well. so I don't think this is a firewall issue.

commands executed in Laptop (192.168.1.102):

```
adp@adp-laptop:~$ ping 192.168.1.101
PING 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=32.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=54.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=77.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=100 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.101 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.193/66.193/100.717/25.463 ms

adp@adp-laptop:~$ telnet 192.168.1.101 80
Trying 192.168.1.101...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

commands executed in PC (192.168.1.101):

```
adp@adp-desktop:~$ ps afx | grep http
12672 pts/4    S+     0:00              |               \_ grep --color=auto http

adp@adp-desktop:~$ ping 192.168.1.102
PING 192.168.1.102 (192.168.1.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=32.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=54.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.102: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=77.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.102: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=100 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.102 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.193/66.193/100.717/25.463 ms
adp@adp-desktop:~$ telnet 192.168.1.102 80
Trying 192.168.1.102...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
adp@adp-desktop:~$ telnet 192.168.1.102
Trying 192.168.1.102...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What should i do?

Comment: Whats in your /etc/apache2/ports.conf?

Comment: @takpar -`ps afx | grep http` on both PC

Comment: @aeby and @ajreal: i provided requested info in the question. thanks.

Comment: I think Its a network problem. not a problem from Apache's Side. Have you checked whether 192.168.1.101:80 is accessible from other PCs ?

Comment: "192.168.1.101:80 is NOT accessible from other PCs". this is exaclty the problem.

Comment: Have you run some portscanner 192.168.1.101 ?

Comment: Run "telnet 192.168.1.101 80" from you .102 box.  If that connection times out, run "iptables -L" on the .101 box to see if the firewall is blocking it.  If not configure your router/switch to allow HTTP traffic to your .101 box.

Answer (score 0):

Because the connection is timed out (not refused) I guess it is a **firewall problem** check if you are using any.

There can still be an other possibility if your kernel is using *black holes* for closed ports (it does not send *connection refused* TCP packets just refuses to answer anything if the port is not used). But you mentioned that you have `Listen 80` in your config file, and that means **all interfaces**, so the chances are good you have a firewall problem after all.

In UFW (the default firewall in Ubuntu) you can add a firewall rule to allow incoming HTTP connections to your box:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from any to 192.168.1.101 port 80
```

Comment: UFW is the default firewall in Ubuntu. If you reside on an intranet you have little need for it (because your router is a natural firewall anyway). you can disable it with: **sudo ufw disable**, but I added an UFW rule to the answer (not tested).